# spring 4 and hibernate 5 integration: could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

- Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.1.0.Final
- HSQLDB 2.3.3

I tried to make the demo integration project as simple as possible. But I ran into the problem `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`. I searched Google and tried a bunch of methods to fix it but still failed.

App.java

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class App implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(App.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.example");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

And here is my hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the demo project https://github.com/reliveyy/spring4-hibernate5-demo

Full stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:132) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
at org.projw.HelloController.onSpringStartup(HelloController.java:51) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:227) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:144) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:106) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1692) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:465) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:415) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [?:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Please, add a full stack trace and the code where an exception is generated.

Comment: @bitweaver Looking at the exception it happened at `HelloController.onSpringStartup(...)`. Do have any active transaction while calling `onSpringStartup(..)` method. I think the exception is because you don't have an active transaction while calling `onSpringStartup(...)`. If so, annotate this method with `@Transactional` attribute and should help.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu sounds reasonable but it will throw org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Transaction not successfully started

Comment: @bitweaver I have just gone through the `onSpringStartup` method and I see it is an `EventListener` that is invoked by Spring. Not sure about when this `EventListener` is getting called by Spring and may be transaction cannot be injected into it or spring transnational initialization is not yet ready to be injected.

Comment: When I use Spring transaction(@Transactional) and Hibernate transaction together, I will get the above exception

Comment: @bitweaver I misinterpreted your earlier comment. So can you remove hibernate transaction code (beginTransaction & commit) and try. Since with Transactional annotation Spring takes care of transaction mgmt.

Comment: So what if I want to only use Hibernate transaction (without @Transactional) inside a method and what should I do?

Comment: When I use Spring @Transactional only, the problem will go.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example");`

instead of

`factoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.example");`

to specify a package to scan.

Try to `open()` and `close()` the `Session` in place of this code

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(person);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: still has the problem

Comment: `sessionFactory.openSession()` and `session.close()` works but why `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` failed and I already set up the `txManager`, `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread`

Comment: @bitweaver `txManager` is for a transactions management. It doesn't control a session. You can try to use `OpenSessionInViewFilter`  to control a session.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

to your Service classes.
I had the same issue. This annotation helped me.